# Trying to figure out how to add multiple CPT or Dx codes to a Rails model Using Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to create a medical records type app, wanted to know what would be the best way to add multiple CPT(Procedure) or Dx(medical diagnosis) codes to a model (E.g. a visit to a medical professional can contain multiple procedures done on the same visit or a person may discuss several ailments, the one making the record of the visit would be the professional and the patient would be able to view it.) So far I have a User model(the patient), a Provider model(the medical professional), a medical record model(belongs to the User) and a Medical Entry model(belongs to the medical record and the provider).

I'm thinking that I would have to create a column for each of code type, so far I' have a column for a primary dx and then secondary dx and that belongs to the medical entry model to limit it to just two for simplicity, but with the CPT column I think it will be a problem since a provider typical will have several CPT codes and each can have a unit count(e.g. Multiple dosages of drug administrations, etc) and each code will have a description. using a text box will get messy since each entry can have multiple CPT codes and I don't think it will ust be a big block of text for each entry.

What would be the best way to organize/execute this idea in the model without having to create an infinite number of columns for the cpt/dx codes and unit counts? Any gems or strategies would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, man. Starting from first principles on something like this is a decidedly bad idea. Go out and look at what others have done. Almost all the major coding systems, ICD-10, LOINC, SNOMED, READ, CPT, etc. have web sites with very substantial resources. Also, go look at Indivo's [data models](http://docs.indivohealth.org/en/2.0/data-models/index.html). Microsoft's Health Vault also has some useful [references](https://developer.healthvault.com/DataTypes). I've been at this for a whole lot of years and there are more ways to get it wrong than there are to get it right. Good luck!

Comment: lol thanks for the input. im definitely a jr level with rails and am glad I asked. im doing this just for myself. but ill keep your input in mind

Comment: No problem. I spent the last ~2-1/2 years building a system for post-acute cardiac care. I'm 20+ years in health tech. Last ~10 years in digital health. I don't think there's a way for you to DM me on SO, but I'll try to keep an eye out in case you have specific questions. Like I said, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to create normalization tables which contain lists of the "master records" diagnosis and proceedures. This is where you would store codes, descriptions, etc:

```
class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
end

class Diagnosis < ApplicationRecord
end
```

This avoids duplication and gives you a structured way to setup your associations.

To apply diagnoses and proceedures to a consultation (a visit) you should setup join models:

```
class Consultation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :doctor
  has_many :patient_proceedures
  has_many :proceedures, through: :patient_proceedures
  has_many :patient_diagnoses
  has_many :diagnoses, though: :patient_diagnoses # Yeah thats really the plural of diagnosis
end

class PatientProcedure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :proceedure
  belongs_to :consultation
end

class PatientDiagnosis < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :diagnosis
  belongs_to :consultation
end
```

This is just a run of the mill many to many association. We can also add the inverse:

```
class Procedure < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_proceedures
  has_many :consultations, through: :patient_proceedures
  has_many :patients, through: :consultations
end

class Diagnosis < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :patient_diagnoses
  has_many :diagnoses, though: :patient_diagnoses 
  has_many :consultations, through: :patient_diagnoses 
  has_many :patients, through: :consultations
end
```